# How to provide file descriptor to a callback function of a promise in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

The below code works fine except in the `closeCallback` function of `.then` of the promise. `closeCallback` requires file descriptor of the opened file which I am unable to provide.

What is the proper way to write this code so that I am able to provide the file descriptor to the `closeCallback` of `.then`?

```
var objHttp = require( 'http' )
var objFs   = require( 'fs' )

function promiseResolveCallback( arg )
{
    console.log("promiseResolveCallback(): ", arg)
}

function promiseRejectionCallback( arg )
{
    console.log("promiseRejectionCallback(): ", arg)
}

function writeToFileCallback()
{
    objFs.writeFile( 'new.js', 
                     'content_to_be_written', 
                     ( argError ) => 
                     { 
                        if( argError ) 
                            throw argError 
                        else 
                            console.log( "writeToFileCallback: Written in new.js!" ) 
                     } 
                   )
}

function readFromFileCallback()
{
    objFs.readFile( 'new.js', 
                    ( argError, argData ) =>
                    {
                        if( argError )
                            console.log( "readFromFileCallback: " + argError )
                        else
                            console.log( "readFromFileCallback: " + argData )
                    }
                  )
}

function closeFileCallback()
{
    objFs.close( argFd, 
                 ( argError ) => 
                 {
                    if( argError )
                        console.log("closeFileCallback: " + argError )
                    else
                        console.log( "closeFileCallback: Closed!" );
                 }
               )
}

function fileFunction()
{                        
     console.log("In fileFunction:")
     // open file
     let objPromise = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) =>
                                   {
                                        objFs.open( 'new.js', 
                                                    'r', 
                                                    ( argError, argFD ) =>
                                                    {
                                                        if( argError )
                                                        {
                                                            reject( new Error("File not found!"), 1000);
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            resolve("File found!", 1000);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                  )
                                   }
                                 );
                            
     objPromise.then( promiseResolveCallback, promiseRejectionCallback )
               .then( writeToFileCallback )
               .then( readFromFileCallback )
               .then( closeFileCallback )
} 

fileFunction()
```

Comment: You don't need to use `fs.close` for those methods you use : `fs.readFile, fs.writeFile`.

Comment: @Eldar I didn't understand what you said. Please explain why close() is not required here and where is it required.

Comment: Close is required when a method acquires a filehandle like `fs.open`. Those methods closes that handle internally.